# How do I use strfind on a cellular array so that only cells containing a certain string are returned?

Tags: matlab

```
AllNetFields = 

'NH0to90'
'SH0to90'
'HemDif0to90'
'Global0to90'
'AsymIndex0to90'
'NH0to14'
'SH0to14'
'HemDif0to14'
'Global0to14'
'AsymIndex0to14'
'NH14to30'
'SH14to30'
'HemDif14to30'
'Global14to30'
'AsymIndex14to30'
'NH30to49'
'SH30to49'
'HemDif30to49'
'Global30to49'
'AsymIndex30to49'
'NH49to90'
'SH49to90'
'HemDif49to90'
'Global49to90'
'AsymIndex49to90'
'GlobalAvg'
```

I'd like to only get the fields containing the phrase 'HemDif" in them.

But if I try

```
>> AllNetFields{strfind(AllNetFields,'HemDif')}
Error using subsindex
Function 'subsindex' is not defined for values of class 'cell'.
```

I get an error (I'm doing it wrong). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do like this:

```
tmp = strfind(AllNetFields,'HemDif');
indexC = find(not(cellfun('isempty', tmp)));

% get strings containing 'HemDif'
AllNetFields{indexC}
```